# Does phantomjs cover more than just chrome?

Tags: phantomjs, web-testing

Phantomjs is webkit based. That means of the major browsers it's really only emulating Chrome, right? Does it provide a mechanism (or is there a way to force it) to provide sufficient test coverage for other browsers, aside from wrapping it in Selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Current PhantomJS is a version of WebKit that is roughly equivalent to Chrome 13 or Safari 5.1, but it is neither of those browsers. (Chrome and Safari behave differently too.) (BTW, PhantomJS 2.0 is hopefully going to have the webkit separately linkable, so you can use different versions.)

If you move to using CasperJS, then your same script can (usually) run with each of PhantomJS and SlimerJS, which will give you test coverage for both WebKit and Gecko (Firefox). SlimerJS also allows you to directly use a local installation of Firefox instead of the supplied Gecko engine, if you wanted to test against different Firefox versions.